# Что такое Pre-trained-model, предварительно обученная модель

Tags: python, tensorflow

следую туториалу [Tensorflow. Object detection API](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).
Вопрос, что такое **"Предварительно обученная модель"** или **"Pre trained model"**? На какие данные она обучена? Как понять, какая именно предобученная модель мне нужна, к примеру из [этого](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2_detection_zoo.md) списка?

Допустим, мне нужен классификатор и детектор холодильников определённой Фирмы, то какую именно модель я должен использовать?

Comment: не знаю что Вы там читаете, но вероятность того что там есть предобученая модель по конкретно Вашему запросу мне кажется крайне мала.

Comment: А что значит для вас "классификатор и детектор"? вам нужно понять не что классифицировать, а как классифицировать. модель - это инструмент.

Answer (score 1):

Предобученная модель тренировалась на каком-то большом (как правило универсальном) наборе данных. Конкретнее про данные нужно смотреть описание к модели.

Подобные модели могут использоваться по разному.

1. К примеру YOLOv5 можно сразу использовать, что бы найти на фотографии какие-то объекты ("машина", "человек") детектировать которые эта нейросеть обучена.
2. Можно подобную модель дообучить на ваших данных (finetune). Это иногда быстрее и качественнее, нежели обучать с нуля. К примеру дообучить (обычно с заморозкой весов в первых слоях) на холодильниках (при этом детектироваться люди и машины станут хуже, нейросеть их частично забудет).
3. Можно "откусить" последние слои и мы получим генератор фич по нашей картинке. На основе этих фич мы самостоятельно можем обучить классификатор (к примеру холодильников). Искать в интернете, к примеру: timm image feature extraction.

Разумеется мы можем подобную модель использовать как часть большой модели. К примеру Stable Diffusion внутри себя использует CLIP.